# How do I open "Windows Search" in a Visual Basic application?

Tags: vb.net, vba, vb6, windows-search

How can I open "Windows Search Companion" or "Windows Basic Search" for a specific folder in an application using Visual Basic ?

[image]

I have found [this article](http://www.ehow.com/facts_6876557_can-always-search-specified-folder_.html), but it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Tags are confusing, vb.Net, Vb6, VBA, which one you want?

Comment: @AkshayJoy All version, if possible.

Comment: I donno this waht you are expecting http://www.ehow.com/how_7536490_do-windows-search-vb.html

Comment: @SiddharthRout Perfect !! Work like a boss!

Comment: @Andriel: Added Code for vb.net as well :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Monster!  :-D

Comment: @Andriel VB6 and VB.Net are VERY different. It's unlikely that you actually want code for both environments.

Comment: @Deanna I know about VB6 and VB.NET they are very different, but this topic I create with the intent to creating a example in general to Visual Basic.

Comment: Personally, I don't think a "general" question really fits on SO when the answers will be very different. Why not open it up to all Win32 capable langauges and accept a "general" "Call ShellExecute() with the `find` verb"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

**VBA/VB6 Code**

```
Option Explicit

'~~> API declaration for the windows "Search Results" dialog
Private Declare Function ShellSearch& Lib "shell32.dll" _
Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, _
ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
ByVal nShowCmd As Long)

Private Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1

Const drv As String = "C:\"

Sub Sample()
    ShellSearch 0, "Find", drv, "", "", SW_SHOWNORMAL
End Sub
```

Tested in VBA

**In Win XP**

[image]

**In Win 7**

[image]

**VB.NET (Tested on Visual Studio Ultimate 64 bit)**

```
'~~> API declaration for the windows "Search Results" dialog
Private Declare Function ShellSearch Lib "shell32.dll" _
Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal lpOperation As String, _
ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
ByVal nShowCmd As Integer) As Integer

Private Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1

Const drv As String = "C:\"

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object,
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ShellSearch(0, "Find", drv, "", "", SW_SHOWNORMAL)
End Sub
```